# How to reference a variable control on a variable form from another form? Need to get the button.Tag renamed in running program

Tags: vb.net, winforms, variables, controls

**Here's my problem:**
I have a form with a treeview.
That treeview shows all:

- other forms in my project as parents
- all buttonnames as childs
- all buttontags as childs of the buttonnames.

When i select a buttonname in the treeview i have the selection presented as
(textbox1 with the buttonname)
(textbox2 with the buttontag)
(textbox3 with the formname)

I have 1 empty textbox which i want to fill manually, to update the buttontag from the button selected in the treeview.

Either way, all code I have tried ain't updating anything.

This is the code so far, but doesn't seem to work...

**My Code:**

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly
    Dim myTypes As Type() = asm.GetTypes()
    Dim frm As Form


    For Each t As Type In myTypes
        If t.IsSubclassOf(GetType(System.Windows.Forms.Form)) AndAlso TextBox1.Text = t.Name Then
            frm = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(t), Form)
            frm.Hide()

            Dim thisButtonName As String = TextBox3.Text ' This is the name of the button I'm looking for
            Dim thisButtonName2 As String = TextBox2.Text ' this is the new tag name for that button
            ' Loop all controls in this form
            For Each ctrl As Control In Controls
                ' Is this control a button
                If TypeOf (ctrl) Is Button Then
                    ' Is this the correct button
                    If CType(ctrl, Button).Name = thisButtonName Then
                        CType(ctrl, Button).Tag = thisButtonName2
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

    TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()

    For Each formprop In My.Forms.GetType.GetProperties
        Dim node = Me.TreeView1.Nodes.Add(formprop.Name)
        Dim form As Form = CType(formprop.GetValue(My.Forms, Nothing), Form)
        ControlsTree(node, form.Controls)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two basic problems here:

1. Your loop `For Each ctrl As Control In Controls` is not iterating over the controls in the other form object referenced by the `frm` variable.  The `Controls` property is going to default to this form's set of Controls, not `frm.Controls`.
2. It seems like you are trying to change the `Tag` in the definition of that class at run-time. That is not possible, AFAIK, especially in what you're trying here. Each time you create a new instance of that form object, you are going to get that object initialized as how it was compiled. You can change the `Tag` values of a running instance of the object, but you can't change the `default` values of the class without using a technique like [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: About number 1 i'm doubting, since i have added a testtextbox and changed the line: CType(ctrl, Button).Tag = thisButtonName2 to testtextbox.text = Ctype(ctrl, button).tag and it does return the tag from the button on the other form.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would be possible. Your code sample shows that you are in a form, and that form has a `Controls` property. If you don't specify which `Controls` property you are looping over, then .Net will default to your current form's `Controls` property. None the less, I would be explicit in your code and change that loop logic to say `frm.Controls`

Comment: yes your correct. My mistake. Was looking to the wrong textbox.

Comment: Is there any chance i'll ever get this to work? Maybe different approach. For example is it possible to assign a database with buttonnumbers from where the tags could be changed? or linked somehow?

Comment: i don't know what your actual goal is here. But you could create a new form, and then assign the `Tag` property of the controls from that form as needed. A database could hold the values of those `Tag` values and set them accordingly.